# Flash FaceBook Infinite Session

Tags: flash, facebook, session

Anyone have any idea of how to create a infinite session so the user just logs in one time once the application has loaded and they remain logged in?

I've tried storing e reseting this informations:

```
var sessionData: Object = 
{
    access_token: "",
    expires: "",
    secret: "",
    session_key: "",
    sig: "",
    uid: ""
};

Facebook.init(APP_ID, onInit, {session: sessionData}, "ACCES_TOKEN");
```

And still when I try:

```
Facebook.login(handler, options);
```

It asks for it again, any insights please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, you just need to init it with right values on the keys and dont call the login again and then you have a infinite session.

Before all that also, you have to ask permission with the key "offline_access"